# Add selected state to single button in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add selected state to my button, the issue I'm having is that every time I click it, it updates the state on every single button when I only want the button clicked to be updated.

The way this app works is when you add a bookmark the button text changes from "Add" to "Added" while also changing the class.

Here is my button component

```
import React from "react";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Button = ({ children, onClick, classname }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={classname}>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </button>
  );
};

Button.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  classname: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Button;
```

Here is my card component, this is where the button is being used.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "../css/Card.scss";
import { useStyles } from "../cssInJs/buttonStyle";
import Button from "./Button";

function Card({ author, title, image, onClick, selected }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="Card__item">
      <div className="Card__spacer">
        <span className="Card__item__authorStyle">{author}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span className="Card__item__titleStyle">{title}</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <Button
          classname={`${selected ? classes.selectedButton : classes.myButton}`}
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          {` ${selected ? "ADDED" : "ADD"}`}
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="Card__item__image">
        <img src={image} alt="article-img" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Card.propTypes = {
  author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Card;
```

and lastly here is where both components meet in the layout component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import "../css/Layout.scss";
import Card from "./Card";
import BookmarksBar from "./BookmarksBar";

function Layout() {
  const { response } = useFetch();

  console.log(response);

  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState([]);
  const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState(false);

  function handleAddBookMark(title) {
    if (!bookmarks.includes(title)) {
      setBookmarks([...bookmarks, title]);
      setSelectedButton(true);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function handleRemoveBookmark(val) {
    var index = bookmarks.indexOf(val);

    if (index > -1) {
      setBookmarks(bookmarks => bookmarks.filter((img, i) => i !== index));
    }
  }

  if (!response || response.length === 0) {
    return <div> Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="Layout__container">
        <div className="Layout__container__mainColumn">
          {response.data.articles.map((article, i) => (
            <Card
              key={i}
              author={article.author}
              title={article.title}
              image={article.urlToImage}
              onClick={() => handleAddBookMark(article.title)}
              selected={selectedButton}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn">
          <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn__customHr" />
          <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn__bookmarks">
            <span>Your bookmarks</span>
            <p>Articles you bookmark will be added to this list</p>
          </div>
          <BookmarksBar data={bookmarks} onClick={handleRemoveBookmark} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

The button state is controlled by the `selectedButton` value. Every time I click the button triggered by the `handleAddBookmark` function it sets `selectedButton` to `true` but the problem is that it sets every single button in the list to be true when I only want the button clicked to be `true`. How do I acheive this?

Comment: You have a single value that meant to track if one of many values has been selected. That's your problem. Maybe instead, selected should be an array with ids of selected items? Then, when you select, you add the id to the array, otherwise you remove. 
Then in your button selected props, you can do condition like ```selected.includes(item.id)```

Comment: @RogerBanks Are you asking that your Card component is re-rendering again and again for any setSelected update?? If so, that's happening due to the `handleAddBookMark` method being passed as prop, without being cached. You can use `useCallback` to fix this.

Comment: That makes sense.. is it possible to provide an example please szczocik?

Answer (score 1):

In `bookmarks` instead of storing only title push id as well. In `selected` check whether that id is already in `bookmarks` array or not. If exist then it will return selected true else false.

In `<BookmarksBar>` Component change the logic as well because now you will pass object which contains title and id. Show title there. And in `handleRemoveBookmark` pass article id which will remove that particular article from `bookmarks` state.

```
function Layout() {
  const { response } = useFetch();

  console.log(response);

  const [bookmarks, setBookmarks] = useState([]);

  function handleAddBookMark({title, id}) {
    if (!bookmarks.filter(b => b.id === id).length) {
      setBookmarks([...bookmarks, {title, id}]);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function handleRemoveBookmark(id) {
    if (id > -1) {
      setBookmarks(bookmarks => bookmarks.filter(b => b.id !== id));
    }
  }

  if (!response || response.length === 0) {
    return <div> Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="Layout__container">
        <div className="Layout__container__mainColumn">
          {response.data.articles.map((article, i) => (
            <Card
              key={i}
              author={article.author}
              title={article.title}
              image={article.urlToImage}
              onClick={() => handleAddBookMark(article)}
              selected={bookmarks.filter(b => b.id === article.id).length ? true : false}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn">
          <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn__customHr" />
          <div className="Layout__container__rightColumn__bookmarks">
            <span>Your bookmarks</span>
            <p>Articles you bookmark will be added to this list</p>
          </div>
          <BookmarksBar data={bookmarks} onClick={handleRemoveBookmark} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: When you're clicking on `handleAddBookMark` with article object that article's title and id inserting correctly into bookmarks?

Comment: Can you add your problem in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Here Saswata Pal, https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-star-f125v?file=/src/components/data.js I changed the data coming from the useFetch as I ran into come CORS issues in the sandbox. Now the data in the app is coming from a fake mock that mirrors the real data structure.

Comment: I see you're still passing article.title instead of article object, also in your mock data id was missing I added id , now it's working

`onClick={() => handleAddBookMark(article)}`

Comment: There was one more issue in bookmarkBar you need to write like 
`  <BookmarksBar data={bookmarks} onClick={handleRemoveBookmark} />
        `

Comment: Check it's working now 
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-surf-pzmig?file=/src/components/Layout.jsx

Comment: thank you! most of it works yes but sadly the mockData I provided was correct, it mirrors the correct payload and there is no id in the aritcles array. However there is one if you go a level deeper into 'articles.source.id' (if you look inside codeandsandbox) so I changed your solution to work with that but now it won't allow me to do remove any bookmarks..

Comment: You need one unique identifier in your array, otherwise you need to make one unique identifier.Without that you'll not able to uniquely identify any card.

Comment: If you not make unique id ,your code will produce bug in future , because as per your mock data your title is not unique.